# VB looping and Excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, pdf

I am writing in vb, and using excels parameters to convert .xls documents to pdf. The process works fine because I am using a string. What I need to know is to somehow loop through the source folder and then convert all files in that folder to pdf and put in the export folder keeping the original file name.  Loops are seriously the bane of my existence in programming even though I know you need it for a solid foundation in this industry.

EXAMPLE:

```
    Dim excelApplication As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
    Dim excelWorkbook As Workbook = Nothing
    Dim paramSourceBookPath As String = "C:\My_Projects\Testing\filename.xls"
    Dim paramExportFilePath As String = "C:\My_Projects\Testing\filename.pdf"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.xls")
    For Each file In files
        'Do Something
    Next
```